# How to execute a block of code right after UIAlertController was dismissed

Tags: swift, uikit, uialertcontroller

Is there a way to execute a block of code on dismissing UIAlertController without subclassing it or involving UIAlertActions?

I need to safely dispose an observable binded to alert's textfiled on its dismissal.

Comment: Please add your UIAlertController code here.

Comment: If you do resort to subclassing and adding a `deinit` or overriding `viewDidDisappear)`  note that Apple specifically state that the UIAlertController is designed to be used 'as-is' and does not support subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must to use the alert action, but if you want, you can mix with completion, like this

```
func showAlertMessageCompletion(titleStr:String, messageStr:String, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default) { (_) in
            completion(true)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add handler to alert action button.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert title", message: "Message to display", preferredStyle: .alert)

// Create OK button
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

    // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
    print("Ok button tapped");

}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

// Create Cancel button
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
    print("Cancel button tapped");
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

// Present Dialog message
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```